# Invisible ReCapcha not calling callback

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have my invisible capcha setup like this:

```
<!-- CAPCHA -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha"
    data-sitekey="6LchqW0UAAAAANOoHruD0Ql5aNJIZld4EwLiaf-W"
    data-callback="capchaDone" data-size="invisible">
</div>
```

And the callback function is defined here:

```
window.capchaDone = function(response) {
    console.log("DONE");
    console.log("RES", response);
};
```

But nothing is ever logged. I have also tried to find a simple implementation of this in Javascript. but there is no real documentation regarding this

Comment: Is the all the code you have on this?

Comment: If you have any CSS for this, I'd suggest that you edit the relevant parts into your question. From the given code snippet it's impossible to infer the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute), if you attach the action to a DIV, you also have to call `grecaptcha.execute();` from JavaScript, for the reCAPTCHA to execute. Let's say you have a form like this:

```html
<!-- CAPTCHA -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha"
    data-sitekey="6LchqW0UAAAAANOoHruD0Ql5aNJIZld4EwLiaf-W"
    data-callback="capchaDone" data-size="invisible">
</div>

<form id="loginForm">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="usernameField" />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordField" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And have a submit eventListener attached to it, you have to call reCAPTCHA in there:

```js
document.querySelector("#loginForm").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  /** Validate input **/
  grecaptcha.execute(); // hand execution off to `data-callback`
});
```

You can then submit the form in your `data-callback` function, after you have validated the response.

```
function capchaDone(response) {
  console.log(response)
  /** Validate reCAPTCHA **/
  document.querySelector("#loginForm").submit() // at last, submit the form
}
```